# What is wrong with this C++ class?

Tags: c++

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
private:
    double width, height;
public:
    Rectangle();
    double Set(double x, double y);
    double getArea();
    double getPerimeter();
};

Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
    width = 1;
    height = 1;
}

double Rectangle::Set(double x, double y)
{
    width = x;
    height = y;
}

double Rectangle::getArea()
{
    double area = height * width;
    return area;
}

double Rectangle::getPerimeter()
{
    double perimeter = (width * 2) + (height * 2);
    return perimeter;
}

int main()
{
    double width, height;
    cout << "Enter the width and height of a rectangle:";
    cin >> width >> height;
    cout << "The area is " << Rectangle::getArea << " and the perimeter is " << Rectangle::getPerimeter << endl;
}
```

When running this code I get the error : "'Rectangle::getArea': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"
I get the same error about the Rectangle::getPerimeter
I am not sure what the problem is, I am new to making classes in C++ obviously, so I am having some trouble. Any suggestions?

Comment: Should be `rectangle.getArea()` and `rectangle.getPerimeter()`. Note the parentheses: that's how you call a function, even when it has no arguments.

Comment: Your class is fine, but you dont use it! You need to create a variable of that type (`Rectangle rect;`), then call member functions ( (`rect.Set(...);`).

Comment: Too many problems, you should get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to start with

Comment: You should learn about floating point numbers.  When you assign to a `double`, prefer to use a floating point constant, such as `1.0`, similarly when multiplying, use `2.0`.

Comment: Your `Set` method lies.  The function *signature* says it returns a value.  The code doesn't return a value.  Maybe you want the return type as `void`.

Comment: Prefer to make methods `const` if they don't modify the data members.  Examples:  `getArea` and `getPerimeter` don't change the members.  This allows the compiler to catch mistakes rather than having the appear during run-time.

Comment: When you call a function, you need to supply `()` and any parameters; otherwise it represents the address of the function.

Answer (score 1):

1st create the object of `Rectangle()` class and then call the respective methods.

`Rectangle rect;/* object of rectangle class */`

your `main()` looks like

```
int main() {
        double width, height;
        cout << "Enter the width and height of a rectangle:";
        cin >> width >> height;
        Rectangle rect;/* object of rectangle class */
        /* calling set method and passing the parameter */
        rect.Set(width,height);
        cout << "The area is " << rect.getArea() << " and the perimeter is " << rect.getPerimeter() << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

As If i understood correctly you don't need `Set()` method actually, instead of this you do the same stuff using *constructor by passing parameters*.

parameterized constructor instead of `Set()` method

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(double x, double y) {
        width = x;
        height = y;
}
```

And create objects like

```
Rectangle rect(width,height);/* it will be called automatically */
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.

1.) You never instantiate the class (i.e. create an object of that class type.) Having two variables with the names `width` and `height` is not the same as having an object of the type Rectangle.

2.) You are trying to call a non-static member function as if they were static member functions. Member functions are called via objects, for example 
`rect.getArea()` where `rect` is an object of the type `Rectangle`.

3.) You are missing the parentheses at the function call. Whenever you get the message `non-standard syntax, use & to create a pointer to a member` it usually means that you have forgotten the parentheses at a function call.

What you want is probably something like:

```
int main()
{
    double width, height;
    cout << "Enter the width and height of a rectangle:";
    cin >> width >> height;
    Rectangle rect;
    rect.Set(width, height);
    cout << "The area is " << rect.getArea() << " and the perimeter is " << rect.getPerimeter() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters this member function returns nothing

```
double Rectangle::Set(double x, double y)
{
    width = x;
    height = y;
}
```

So it should be defined like

```
void Rectangle::Set(double x, double y)
{
    width = x;
    height = y;
}
```

It seems you mean

```
//...
cin >> width >> height;
Rectangle r;
r.Set( width, height );

cout << "The area is " << r.getArea() << " and the perimeter is " << r.getPerimeter() << endl;
```

The functions `getArea` and `getPerimeter` should be declared as constant member functions

```
double getArea() const;
double getPerimeter() const;
```

because they do not change objects of the type Rectangle.

It would be logical consistent if the class had a constructor with two parameters

```
Rectangle( double width, double height );
```

And the method `Set` should be split into two methods like `setWidth` and `setHeight`.

Comment: return statement also missing in main

Comment: @Roushan45 It is not required. A program without return statement in main is well-formed.

Comment: But i have read that its good practice to write return statement , because some its behaves unexpectedly

Comment: @Roushan45 It behaves expectedly because its behavior is described in the C++ Standard. Read the C++ Standard.